# how to run all queue jobs in one line

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-5.5

Can someone know how can I run in one command to Laravel artisan work on all queue in project?

I know that I can run something like that `nohup php artisan queue:work --queue=admin_contact_message_mail,user_get_message_notification,user_get_message_mail --daemon &` , but I have a huge list of queues and asks is there any way to call it all in once or I need to list them all to queue run it and listen it?

Comment: `php artisan queue:listen`

Comment: it's didn't work to me.Save jobs to database but didn't execute it.

Comment: what will u get while running `php artisan queue:listen`

Comment: I didn't get any feedback in console, only save data into database, where laravel saved in jobs table data like: queue name, data and class which will execute attempts is always 0. And when run `php artisan queue:work --queue=user_get_message_mail ` it's run that queue and send mail as normal do. I'm change in /env file to be `QUEUE_DRIVER=database`

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan queue:listen` will do the job!

Comment: it's didn't work to me.Save jobs to database but didn't execute it.

Comment: @StojanKukrika did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: i need to know also

Comment: @sulaiman yes, I find a solution... I make a smaller list of queue name because it was too hard to memorise all of them.

Comment: @AdRock see my prev replay